# Why the map data doesn't appear on ganache while the transaction succeed?

Tags: flutter, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle, ganache

I'm develping dApp using flutter and smart contract - truffle - ganache
i've made a sign up function and integrate it with flutter and its working fine and the data received in ganache in the transaction details , but the map of users which supposed to store the data is empty..
also when i try to login it says there are no user ?
[Shows the data received the from flutter app (successful transaction )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10smZ.png)[Show empty map !! while it suppose to store the data passed[trying to login but there are no data , check the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6UKo.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYVFv.png)

i think ganache does not support ,mapping yet idk, but anyway it suppose to login

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.